# delete dynamic character from string

Tags: java, android, string, char

I have a string containing numbers separated with `,`. I want to remove the `,` before the first character.

The input is `,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`, and this code does not work:

```
results.replaceFirst(",","");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Java. Calling a method on a string will not modify the string itself, but will instead *return a new string*.

In order to capture this new string, you need to assign the result of the operation back to a variable:

```
results = results.replaceFirst(",", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String str = ",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
if(Objects.nonNull(str) && str.startsWith(",")){
  str = str.substring(1, str.length());
}
```

it will remove `,` at first position

Answer (score 0):

you can also do like this ..

```
String str = ",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
String stre = str.replaceFirst("^,", "");
Log.e("abd",stre);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String str = ",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
str = str .startsWith(",") ? str .substring(1) : str ;
System.out.println("output"+str);  // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```